# Policies in Windows update

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-update

I have a laptop that is telling me there are policies set on the device from group policy. This is the only PC that is showing me those policies, I even kicked this laptop out of my domain and I'm still unable to resume updates, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Typically the policies are located in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate and HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate. You could rename those two registry keys and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `gpresult.exe /H gpresult.htm` and open the resulting report. It will show all settings that have been applied by group policies (including local AND/OR domain GPOs). This will help you identify whether there are domain GPO settings still stuck on the device OR if there are local GPO settings that you can change by running `gpedit.msc` locally as an admin.

[image: A sample screen snipping from a gpresult report, showing policy name, setting data, and the Winning GPO name (with some names redacted).]